# Error showing image with imshow

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I was trying out opencv python.
Initially,it was working fine.
I was loading and saving images and it worked.
Suddenly,the same code started giving errors.

```
import numpy as np import cv2

img = cv2.imread('C:\Users\Tanu\Desktop\8ballpool.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('image',img) cv2.waitKey(0)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>           cv2.imshow('image',img)
>       error: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win32-vc12-static\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:281: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow

Comment: you need to escape the file path: `C:\\Users\\ ... \\image.jpg`

Comment: you can rectify the error and verify the answer below ...

Answer (score 0):

That error means that opencv read an empty image. As was suggested in the comments, you'll need to escape the paths as well as ensure that image is actually valid.